# Adobe PDF x64 ifilter

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, adobe, ifilter

Getting a weird error box when using the 64bit version of adobepdf ifilter for sql server 2005 x64 on a x64 windows server 2003.

The exact message box contents:

**MessageBoxHeader:** MsFTEFD.exe - Unable to locate component

**MessageboxContent:**
This application has failed to start because adobepdfl.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem.

Has anyone an idea what to do here?
Re-installation of the ifilter did not solved the problem (including the steps needed to register the filter correctly to work with SQL server), Google does not pop up with any solution. Checked the application & system logs with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really programming related. However, I would look into whether you are running 64 bit SQL server, and whether the filter plugin is 64 or 32 bit.

Comment: well, programming in terms of sql I would say -> full-text-search over pdf files is working correctly or not with having this error message box being displayed.